# Cisco Switch (not ISE/ACE) redirect HTTP server to HTTPS

Tags: cisco

I wish to enable HTTPS server on Cisco , and redirect HTTP to HTTPS, instead of simply disabling HTTP.

Is this possible?

Current config:

```
no ip http server
ip http secure-server
```

Comment: You cannot do that, and you should really disable both for security.

Comment: You need https for RESTCONF